# paypal recurring payments - sudden death

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

We are setting up PayPal recurring payments - customers able to use a PayPal account or a credit card processed through PP.

Payments going through fine and customer accounts upgrade.
The issue we have is when customers cancel - it works, but immediately.

We want their subscription benefits to remain until the next end of their subscription period - hope that makes sense.

At the moment we are getting a "sudden death" scenario, where their accounts are downgrading immediately, rather than at the end of their subscription period.

If anyone has any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, wouldn't "benefits" and "downgrading" be at your end (those are your business rules)? Paypal handles the transaction part (only).

Comment: Hi EdSF - yes, so an issue at our end. I was just wondering if there is anything in the PP recurring payment setup that can deal with this. Apologies if a deeply lame question.

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do is setup your own system to handle that.  So when your user cancels, mark that in your database along with the date that you actually want the profile to be canceled.  Then you can setup a CRON job on your server to run a script that actually processing the cancellation via the API on the actual day you want it to cancel.